# How to make fast showing alt hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need to do this is, show title="showtext" hover make fast when mouseover it. can you help me?
html

```html
 <a alt="showtext" href="#" title="showtext"> show text </a>
```

Comment: Use a custom tooltip, you cannot control default time for showing up your title text

Comment: thank you @Mr.Alien, will write custom tooltip.